# Insert Multiple Records (More than one result Error) But I need to insert for all

Tags: postgresql, insert, multiple-columns, postgresql-8.4

I am trying to Insert few lines into my db using this ex.

```
INSERT INTO product_line
(product_line_ID, m_product_id,
 process_type, process_time) 
VALUES 
(get_uuid(),(SELECT M_PRODUCT_ID FROM M_PRODUCT WHERE product_name='DKP'),  //this will return multiple results
'L', now());
```

I know that I will get Multiple Results from select query Error, But I want it to insert same for all results got from select query.

How do i do this?

Insert same statement for all Products came in select loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean something like:

```
INSERT INTO ...
SELECT get_uuid(), m_product_id, 'L', now()
FROM m_product
WHERE ...
```

This will insert one row for each you select from m_product.